# How create custom interface with key from other interface?

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
enum mycustomlist {
  football = 0,
  handball = 1,
  basketball = 2,
  chess = 3,
  swimming = 4
}
```

and I need a new interface where i need to have

```
optional key (from mycustomlist): boolean
```

example:

```
{
  0: true,
  1: false,
  2: true,
  3: false
}

{
  2: false
}

{
  3: true,
  2: false
}
```

I try:

```
player: {
  <list>: boolean
}
```

but i have error ((

How I can to create this?

Answer (score 2):

So basically this is how it should work:

```
enum List {
    football = 0,
    handball = 1,
    basketball = 2,
    chess = 3,
    swimming = 4
}

type MyType = {
    [P in List]: boolean
}
```

The problem is that it results in the following error:

> error TS2322: Type 'List' is not assignable to type 'string'

This is an open issue: [Enums can no longer be used for index signature types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13042) and should be resolved in version `2.4`.

The discussion for this started in this issue: [Index signature parameter type should allow for enums](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2491)